# Chrome Extensions- unable to send HTTP requests through an HTML form?

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Within my google chrome extension, I'm trying to take a simple html form and submit POST data to an endpoint. However, for some reason I can't figure out, it always fails.  Using the developer tools to inspect the popup, I see that my request always ends up as "canceled," as seen in the screenshot below.

[chrome developer tools screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3yll.png)

This issue only arises specifically when I'm using an HTML form.  I can successfully send requests and get data back if I use jQuery or make an XMLHttpRequest so it's not a permissions thing; I also can successfully send requests if I run the exact same HTML in a full web browser.  But whenever I try in a chrome extension with an HTML form, the request always gets "canceled."

Here is my code:

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Forms",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description" : "Description ...",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "That's the tool tip",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

popup.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form action="http://httpbin.org/post" method="post">
      First Name
      <input type="text" name="firstname">
      Last Name
      <input type="text" name="lastname">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I see no reason why the above shouldn't work just fine in a chrome extension but every time I click the "submit" button my request ends up as canceled.  Any help or insight would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The popup is an internal page with chrome-extension:// URL which cannot be redirected to another http URL via POST. Use `submit` listener with `preventDefault` + `XMLHttpRequest`, there are many examples.

Comment: I've already said I can successfully write some javascript that uses XMLHttpRequest send POST data to the http://httpbin.org/post endpoint, and I can also print the successful response back in the console.  I'm just confused as to why this does not work using the seemingly equivalent method of HTML forms and why my request gets canceled when doing it this way.

Comment: Okay, the first clause in my comment explained that, ignore the second one.

Comment: I see; is the issue that when submitting this HTML form, the form isn't simply returning data, but actually trying to redirect the page away to httpbin.org/post ? If so, that might explain why I can see the data using an XMLHttpRequest but it doesn't work when using the form.

Comment: @wOxxOm, Do you have a good question to use as a dup-target?  We've seen basically this issue a couple/few times recently, but I'm not easily finding a good target for closing them as duplicates.

Comment: @Makyen, I don't see any as well, and I really don't know what to say in answer for the problem as it seems too obvious (I don't like answering in such cases so I just comment).

Comment: @user2437424 Hey! Did you found any solution? I am also stuck at similar problem

Comment: From what I understand from what @wOxxOm explained, the precise thing I'm trying to do in this case is impossible.  Submitting this form involves navigating to another http:// URL when the response happens, and that can't be done in a page with a chrome-extension://  URL.